# How do I share self hosted BitBucket Windows Pipeline runner across main and fork repositories

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-cloud

I have a main BitBucket repo say project.git. I have a self hosted Windows runner setup to monitor changes to this repo and kick off a build. It has been working great.

I forked the repo to say joe.git. I want to test my changes in joe.git before promoting them to project.git with a pull request. I want to reuse the runner setup for project.git. I don't see any option for my fork to reuse the runner that was already setup for project.git. The only option is to add a new runner for the fork; start it and then commit changes.

Don't you think it is unnecessary?

Wondering if there is any trick to make main repo runners available to forks...

Thanks